# splitting a string by specific letters while preserving them in the string

Tags: python

I'm trying to split a string by specific letters(in this case:'r','g' and'b') so that I can then later append them to a list. The catch here is that I want the letters to be copied to over to the list as well.

```
string = '1b24g55r44r'
```

What I want:

```
[[1b], [24g], [55r], [44r]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re

print([match for match in re.findall('[^rgb]+?[rgb]', '1b24g55r44r')])
```

**Output**

```
['1b', '24g', '55r', '44r']
```

The regex match:

- `[^rgb]+?` everything that is not rgb one or more times
- followed by one of `[rgb]`.

If you need the result to be singleton lists you can do it like this:

```
print([[match] for match in re.findall('[^rgb]+?[rgb]', '1b24g55r44r')])
```

**Output**

```
[['1b'], ['24g'], ['55r'], ['44r']]
```

Also if the string is only composed of **digits** and `rgb` you can do it like this:

```
import re

print([[match] for match in re.findall('\d+?[rgb]', '1b24g55r44r')])
```

The only change in the above regex is `\d+?`, that means match one or more digits.

**Output**

```
[['1b'], ['24g'], ['55r'], ['44r']]
```